# Jquery using individual blinking text counters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button which when user press, it will create a message and blink it 5 times. But the problem is it every time I press the button, the message before will also blink with the new message together. I want the new message to blink individually 5 times every time pressing the button.

html:

```
<div id="result"></div>
<button id="but">Blink again 1</button>
```

js:

```
var counter = 0;
var i = 0;
function blink(selector){
$(selector).fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $(this).fadeIn('slow', function(){
        if(counter++ <= 5)
        blink(this);
    });
});
}

$("#but").click(function() {
i++;
counter = 0;
$('#result').prepend("<div class='num'>Number " + i + "</div>");
blink('.num');
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Vaysf/870/)

I found out that maybe the problem is that I only use one counter to blink. That's why all the message blink together. But how do I create a new counter everytime the button is press? How do the blink function know which counter to use? I've tried many ways but failed. Do you guys have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It is because all added dvis have same selector class num.

Something like this:

```
$("#but").click(function() {
    i++;
    counter = 0;
    sel = 'num' + i;
    $('#result').prepend("<div class='"+sel+"'>Number " + i + "</div>");
    blink('.' + sel);
});
```

Comment: why is blink go all the way to 7?

Comment: counter from 0 to 5 inclusive (6) and you blinking text before checking condition.

Comment: I have tried your method. But seems like all of them stop together everytime they blink. I still think its the counter problem.

Comment: it is because your counter is global.

Comment: That's why my question is how to create a new counter every time the button is press. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATE:*** As "*But I want the old message to continue blinking to 5 times too.*" .. [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ez8z1ub5/1/)

```js
var counter, i = 0;

function blink(selector) {
    for(counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++){
     $(selector).fadeOut('slow').fadeIn('slow');
    }
}

$("#but").click(function () {
    ++i;
    counter = 0;
    $('#result').prepend('<div id="id-' + i + '">Number ' + i + '</div>');
    blink('#id-' + i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
<button id="but">Blink again 1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I found out that maybe the problem is that I only use one counter to
>   blink. That's why all the message blink together. But how do I create
>   a new counter everytime the button is press?

Try creating different class name for each click on button. Using `.selector` , though deprecated, to filter specific element to avoid all elements `html` being updated simultaneously. If used selector `.num:eq(n)` , when `.prepend()` called again, existing `.num` element would no longer be at index `0` , causing both, or all elements to blink at once.

```js
function blink(callback) {
  var sel = $(this.selector);
  if (sel.data().count === undefined) {
    sel.data("count", blink.counter);
  }
  sel.fadeOut('slow', function() {
    sel.fadeIn('slow', function() {
      if (sel.data().count < blink.max) {
        sel.data().count = 1 + sel.data().count;
        callback.call(sel);
        sel.blink(callback.bind(sel));
      } else {
        sel.data().count = blink.counter
      }
    });
  });
}

blink.counter = 0;
blink.max = 5;

$.fn.blink = blink;

var i = 0;
$("#but").click(function() {
  $('#result').prepend("<div class=num-" + i + ">Number</div>");
  $(".num-" + i).blink(function() {
    $(this).append($(this).data().count)
  });
  ++i;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="result"></div>
<button id="but">Blink again 1</button>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Vaysf/876/